# APIs that parse data from email

Tags: mysql, api, parsing, email, pop3

I'm attempting to create an product that needs to parse particular data fields from emails and enter them in a MYSQL database.

Are there any APIs that can be utilised to avoid having to code this from scratch?

Comment: Any particular language, or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaMail API to fetch mails from POP3/IMAP coservers

Comment: OP specifically requested functionality of extracting data from the email, not fetching emails.